Jupyter Notebook pass python list of strings to bash cell
Within a Jupiter Notebook (Python kernel) I would like to pass a list of strings to a %%bash cell to use in a for loop.
I can do the following:
message = 'hello'
messages = ['hello', 'there']

%%bash -s {message}
echo $1

This works fine. But when I try to pass the list messages in the manner below I get '[hello,'.
%%bash -s {messages}
for i in $1@
do
    echo $i
done


Based on concatenating the list to a string using Python's join() string method and this answer to 'How to iterate over arguments in a Bash script':
In your earlier Python cell:
message = 'hello'
messages = ['hello', 'there']
messages_as_strings = " ".join(messages)

Then in the other Bash cell:
%%bash -s {messages_as_strings}
for i in $@
do
    echo $i
done

Or....
Combine to streamline
Or imagine you only had your Python block:
message = 'hello'
messages = ['hello', 'there']

Then in the Bash cell:
%%bash -s {" ".join(messages)}
for i in $@
do
    echo $i
done

